# Почему выводит 1?

Tags: c++

Почему выводит `1`?

```
long int i = -0xffffffff;
std::cout << i;
```

Comment: Почему нет?  Если вы записали 1 в переменную, то что она содержит?

Comment: У меня другое получается - `-‭4294967296‬`

Comment: Какой у вас компилятор? И сколько у вас `sizeof(int)`?

Comment: @Ser: Вы что-то выдумываете.  `-‭4294967296‬` тут не может быть никак.

Comment: @Ser, ты в линуксе что ли проверял?

Comment: @Qwertiy♦: Проверяем "в линуксе": http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e567adfb28583d4d

Answer (score 5):

`0xffffffff` имеет тип `unsigned int` <sup>†</sup>.

Результат применения унарного `-` к `unsigned` типам - это `2N - x` (где `N` - размер типа в битах). [Пруф.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Unary_arithmetic_operators)

Так что `-0xffffffff` = `-(unsigned int)4294967295‬` = `(unsigned int)(42949672956 - 4294967295‬)` = `(unsigned int)1`.

Когда результат преобразуется в `long`, он, естественно, остается единицей.

---

<sup>†</sup> Это верно только если размер `int`а - 32 бита. Принцип такой:

Если целочисленный литерал не влезает в `int`, то компилятор будет пробовать типы большего размера, пока один из них не подойдет: `int`, `unsigned int`, `long`, `unsigned long`, и т. п.
<sub>(Такая последовательность типов используется, если литерал без суффикса, и не десятичный. Для десятичных без суффикса `unsigned ...` не проверяются. Почему?  - ¯\_(ツ)_/¯, пруфы и подробности [здесь](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.icon#2).)</sub>

С 32-битными `int`ами, первым подходит `unsigned int`.

С 64-битными - обычный `int`, и итоговый ответ будет `-‭4294967295`.

Comment: Так как гарантируемый диапазон `int` в С и С++ является "16-битным", теоретически возможно, что первым подходящим типом для `0xFFFFFFFF` станет `long` или `unsigned long`. А дальше все будет развиваться как описано в ответе.

Answer (score 2):

Оператор унарный минус, примененный к беззнаковому типу, дает результат аналогичный вычитанию этого числа из 2 в степени (количество бит в числе).

```
2^32 - 0xffffffff
‭4294967296‬ - ‭4294967295‬ 
1
```